# Making dynamic forms in objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, forms, uitableview, generics

I've a very difficult thing to do. What I need to do is the following. I've a tableview that have the following rows.

```
cell1: Login-form
cell2: Vacation-form
cell3: contact-form
```

What I want do know is when a cell is pushed the correct form is displayed. Well this maybe looks very simple. But the problem is that I can have 20 different forms in this tableview. So  what I want to do is to make generic forms. So that when I click on a cell it goes to the next view and this view is filled up with the correct form. So when I click on *Login-form* that view will be a login form. But when I go back an click on *contact-form* that same view should be a contact form.

I hope you can see my problem. What I have so far is that when you click on a cell a NSArray is been created that contains dictionarys that looks the following

```
dict1: {
     key: "label"
     object: "Login"
     key: "textField"
     object: "text"
}
dict2:  {
     key: "label"
     object: "pass"
     key: "textField"
     object: "passText"
}
```

But know when I go to the next view controller it should be filled up with this labels and textfield/passwordField.

I think I found a very good library for forms. You can find it over [here](https://github.com/escoz/QuickDialog). 
Any ideas what my next step should be?

Kind regards.